# C++ const overload and code sharing

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

I have a class that have member method f and g, both overloaded by const. There are
calls to g() within f(). The method body for f and const f is the same.

```
class X {
 void f() {/body ... g() /} const;
 void f() {/body g() /};

 void g() const;
 void g();
};
```

Since f() and g() have the same method body, I would really like to have one method,
rather than have duplicated code copied between f and const f.

Moreover, when the body of f() is executed for a const object, I want the obvious const g() 
executed (and non-const g() for non-const objects).

Comment: @cu3dots: he implies that the `g()` functions differ, and the `f() const` will probably call `g() const` even for nonconst X.

Comment: Doesn't one normally overload for constness to propagate the constness of the return value (rather than to get different behaviors)? Is there more than meets the eye?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this can be done with template member functions (but I could easily be wrong); so the best option may be to factor the shared code out into another method.

```
class X {
    void g() const;
    void g();

    void body() const { ... }

    void f() const { body(); g(); }
    void f() { body(); g(); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From a different point of view, you won't have duplicated code, since not the same `g()` is called in your `f()`'s. What you could do is break down the code in f:

```
class X {
 void body() {};
 void f() {body(); g() } const;
 void f() {body(); g() };

 void g() const;
 void g();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this:

```
class X {
 void body(){/body ... /} const;
 void f() {body(); g(); } const;
 void f() {body(); g(); };

 void g() const;
 void g();
};
```

If you can't, is it because /body .../ has a const and non-const version?

If so, even though it's the same source, it is a different meaning -- it would compile differently, so you can't share source unless you mean sharing the actual lines of code, not by calling a function.

Some ideas:

1. Make body a macro
2. Put body in body.inc and #include it into the methods (kind of overkill)

Comment: what if class X had many methods of type g() overloaded by const, so that separating the code into body() g() was not feasible ?

Comment: Then, you need the same code to be repeated -- a macro is a way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
class X {
 void f_impl() const { /body }
 void f() {f_impl(); ... g(); /} const;
 void f() {f_impl(); g(); /};

 void g() const;
 void g();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement f in a template function, which is passed `(X*)this` or `(const X*)this`.

```
#include <cstdio>

class X {
    void g() const { std::puts("const"); }
    void g() { std::puts("non-const"); }

    void body() const { }

public:
    void f() const { f_impl(this); }
    void f() { f_impl(this); }

private:
    template <class Self>
    static void f_impl(Self* self)
    {
        self->body();
        self->g(); 
    }
}; 

int main()
{
   X x;
   x.f();
   const X y = {};
   y.f();
}
```

(It is probably not very nice having to implement large functions in headers for this, though.)